# Upgrade won't allow second display to go to 1920x1080

Tags: 10.10, xorg, multiple-monitors, display, xrandr

I just upgraded to 10.10 last night and I'm having issues now with dual display from my laptop dock. This was working in the previous release with a manual xrandr command:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --off --output DP1 --mode 1920x1080 && xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1920x1080 --left-of DP1
```

When I run this now, the DP1 output doesn't have a mode for 1920x1080. The two displays are a matched pair of dell 22" that are both 1920x1080. The laptop/dock is a Lenovo X201 with the Intel graphics in it. The dock does VGA and DisplayPort out.

When I attempt to manually add the mode

```
xrandr --addmode DP1 1920x1080
```

and rerun my command, I lose both displays altogether. I have to then blindly reset to just one of them in order to get display back.

If I avoid the 1920 and just attempt to setup DP1 at the 1280x1024 max it thinks it has, then the second display will come up, but obviously looks horrible since it's non-native resolution.

I've grabbed the updated xorg intel driver from the stable X ppa and am running:

```
2:2.13.901-2ubuntu2~xup~maverick
```

xrandr output

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
LVDS1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1280x800       60.2 +
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1
```

I've submitted a bug report here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/729788

Comment: It looks like you're using addmode incorrectly. You're not giving it the refresh rates.  According to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Adding_undetected_resolutions that syntax is only to be used if the resolution is already in the list. Try doing what it says below that using a full mode line generated from `cvt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've lived with this for a long time, but a week ago I picked up a kernel update that seems to have fixed everything. I've now got by dual HDMI displays working great out of the laptop dock.

Answer (score 0):

may I ask you which kernel u have in use?

I am stuck on the same problem that all video output through the docking station wont work.

My kernel is:

```
Linux linuxmint 3.8.0-030800rc7-generic #201302081635 SMP Fri Feb 8 21:36:17 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

.

EDIT: I was able to fix it on my own by not using my KVM switch (ATEN CS1784).

Comment: Please separate *answers*, *questions* and *comments* - All of these have their own sections and you should not combine them in one post. Please detail only your *answer* here - if it actually answers the question (otherwise post a *new* question and *answer it yourself* with this information, please).